# Fibonnacci sequence using Arrays and For Loops

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

This program is to create a wave like structure using C# with the fibonnaci sequence and arrays. With the number of the sequence being at the end and asterisks equaling what number is on the current line in front. This is all done using the For loops and having the upper limiter done by the Array, I solve that limiter problem by using the .Length aspect of Arrays but I don't grasp the concept of how to properly use the array within this sequence.

This first part of code I have the sequence building up using my array with 12 index as I only need the 11 first fibonacci sequences.
The problem I am running into is within the second part of the code.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 0, b = 1;

            int[] fibArray = new int[12];
            fibArray[0] = 0;
            fibArray[1] = 1;

            Console.WriteLine("0");
            Console.WriteLine("*1");

            for (int i = 3; i <= fibArray.Length; i++)
            {

                
                fibArray[i] = a + b;
                a = b;
                b = fibArray[i];
                             

                for(int y = 1; y <= fibArray[i]; y++)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }

                
                Console.Write("" + fibArray[i]);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

With this second part of code I am unable to get it to register and output the sequence. Mostly I am unsure of how to properly set up my array to ensure that the fibonacci sequence is able to go reverse as well. I understand the sequence is typically f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2), I cannot wrap my head around how to properly use arrays in this context.

```
            for (int p = fibArray[11]; p >= fibArray.Length; p--)
            {

                for (int k = 1; k <= p; k++)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");  
                }
                Console.Write(""+ b);
                Console.WriteLine();                                           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for ranting, just trying to explain the code as a whole but to give a sum of what I am asking about.
It would be how to use the Arrays, what I did wrong with my current code, and what aspect I could use to control the loops using the Array itself.

To give an overall example of the desired output it would be like so:

```
0
*1
*1
**2
***3
***3
**2
*1
*1
0
```

Comment: your 2nd loop should start from `11`, not `fibArray[11]` and go down to 0, and your print should be `fibArray[p]` instead of `b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to note about your original code.  You manually set the first two values in the sequence at elements 0 and 1, but then skipped over element 2 and started from element 3.  Your loop was including the length of the array as valid index when it should start at (array length - 1) since arrays are zero based in .Net.

You can output the correct length of asterisks by using this [string constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_).

I'd separate the generation of the sequence from the output:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // building the Fibonacci sequence (no output at this time)
    int[] fibArray = new int[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < fibArray.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                fibArray[i] = 0;
                break;

            case 1:
                fibArray[i] = 1;
                break;

            default:
                fibArray[i] = fibArray[i - 1] + fibArray[i - 2];
                break;
        }
        
    }

    // increasing curve
    for (int i = 0; i < fibArray.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new String('*', fibArray[i]) + fibArray[i].ToString());
    }
    // decreasing curve
    for (int i = (fibArray.Length-1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new String('*', fibArray[i]) + fibArray[i].ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
0
*1
*1
**2
***3
*****5
********8
*************13
*********************21
**********************************34
*******************************************************55
*****************************************************************************************89
*****************************************************************************************89
*******************************************************55
**********************************34
*********************21
*************13
********8
*****5
***3
**2
*1
*1
0

Press Enter to Quit
```

Comment: Really appreciate this code example using a switch. Helped me understand that you can label the integer i for multiple areas. Kind of an oversight within my own knowledge but helped fix the gap and understand that you can also subtract from the .Length within the array! Again Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Be sure to upvote or accept at some point.  ;)